# How to re-use custom validation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to use the same custom validation in several forms. In other frameworks I would create a new "Validator" class but I'm not sure what's best with Django/Python.

Below is what I did, is there a better way (solution below)?

In any **form**:

```
    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")

        return validate_image_with_dimensions(
            image,
            expected_width=965,
            expected_height=142
        )
```

In a **validation** module

```
def validate_image_with_dimensions(image, expected_width, expected_height):
    from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

    # the validation code...

    return image
```

---

**Below is the solution:**

In the **form**:

```
    image = forms.ImageField(
        max_length=250,
        label=mark_safe('Image<br /><small>(must be 1100 x 316px)</small>'),
        required=True,
        validators=[
            ImageDimensionsValidator(
                expected_width=1100,
                expected_height=316
            )
        ]
    )
```

In a **validation** module:

```
class ImageDimensionsValidator(object):

    def __init__(self, expected_width, expected_height):
        self.expected_width = expected_width
        self.expected_height = expected_height

    def __call__(self, image):
        """
        Validates that the image entered have the good dimensions
        """
        from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

        if not image:
            pass
        else:
            width, height = get_image_dimensions(image)
            if width != self.expected_width or height != self.expected_height:
                raise ValidationError(
                    "The image dimensions are: " + str(width) + "x" + str(height) + ". "
                    "It's supposed to be " + str(self.expected_width) + "x" + str(self.expected_height)
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form and model fields [accept a list of validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#writing-validators):

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
   ...
   image = forms.ImageField(validators=[validate_image_with_dimensions])
```

A validator is a callable object of any kind, feel free to write callable classes (django internal validators are class-based).

For inspiration, look at [django.core.validators source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm completing my question with the working example.